# Bilinear transformations in one variable complex analysis.

Tags: complex-analysis

I am self studying complex analysis 1st time from complex variables and applications from ponnusamy and silverman. 
I got struck on this question:
find all bilinear transformations mapping imaginary axis onto unit circle. 
I tried assuming a general bilinear transformation w = (az+b )/(cz+d)  and equating its modulus to 1. But couldn't get anything.
It's on ch-3 page 84 ex no -19
Please help.

Comment: Do you mean [linear fractional transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_fractional_transformation)? The term "bilinear" is usually used for functions with two arguments that are linear in both of them.

Comment: A fact you might use is that a complex fractional linear transformation is already determined by the images of any three points.

Comment: Yes,  I mean linear fractional transformations

Comment: 0x539 - could you please elaborately tell steps to reach the answer.  I could not do much despite trying.  I knew that it has to do something with three points ,  but could not apply it. Please help.

Comment: Linear fractional transformations are completely determined by how they act on three inputs (one might think 4 inputs, since there are 4 parameters, but you can divide one of them out without changing the transformation). I suggest that you find the transformation that takes sends $0 \to 1, i \to i, \infty \to -1$.